# Why "пишешь", "пишем", "пишете", not "пишёшь", "пишём", "пишёте"

Tags: грамматика, правописание, буква-ё

A task asked me to conjugate the verb писать in present tense and I thought it whould have these endings:
я пишу,
ты пишёшь,
он/она пишёт,
мы пишём,
вы пишёте,
они пишут

But I checked the wiktionary and it tells me it is conjugated this way:
я пишу,
ты пишeшь,
он, она пишeт,
мы пишeм,
вы пишeте,
они пишут

Why doesn't the e change to ё??? When ю changes to у?

Answer (score 10):

Ё changes into non-stressed "е" after ш and ж. You get same result with лизать: Я лижу, ты лижешь, мы лижем. When the word is one-syllable, so it's obviously stressed, it remains Ё. Although I can think of only one example: ты лжёшь, вы лжёте

Comment: @SupEvan, would be great if you accepted (ticked) the answer besides saying "thanks".

Comment: Here are two other examples similar to лгу: жгу and стригу (the word стригу has two syllables).

Answer (score 1):

Endings of the so-called first conjugation have ё if they are under stress, otherwise they have е. One must learn where the endings are stressed and where they are not, although endings, not including the -у/-ю for first person singular, are either all stressed or all not stressed.

You cannot have ю after "shibilants" (ж, ч, ш, and щ) so you have to write у there. Not after shibilants ю is written if there is a palatalised (soft) consonant before it or if there is a vowel (in this case there actually *is* a jot, which is a soft consonant, but it is not written because *йу changes to ю).